# how to resolve magento admin manage categories orange screen error?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I'm using magento 1.7.0.2 version.and suddenly i got error in

> **admin >   catalog         > manage categories page**

with orange screen.i tried lot like adding following function
n file:

> **app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Product.php**

, add this    class method:

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
return $this->getUrl(’*/*/edit’, array(’page_id’ => $row->getId()));
}
```

but it's not working.Please kindly guide me.

Comment: Suggestion: If you haven't done anything more on this file, try replacing it with unchanged 'Product.php' file from any fresh magento folder, and see if the error is due to this file or not.

Comment: i replaced entire folder but nothing happend .still i face same problem.i'm unable to add categories